# Indexing geojson as object into geoshape worked with Nest 5.0.1, but does not with Nest 6.4.2?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

We are upgrading from elasticsearch 5.2 to elasticsearch 6.4.2, and therefore also from Nest 5.0.1 to Nest 6.4.2.
In 5.0.1 we could index geoJSON data as an object, but Nest 6.4.2 generates a request containing geoJSON without data.

We index a field with geographic data in geoJSON format to a geoshape field in elasticsearch like this:

In class GeoDocument:

```
[Nest.Text(Name = "field1")]
public string Field1 { get; set; }
[Nest.GeoShape(Name = "geometrie")]
public object Geometrie { get; set; }
```

Data:

```
string polygon = "{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[5.856956,51.002753],[5.856928,51.002771],[5.856687,51.002853],[5.856956,51.002753]]]}";
```

Serialize data to object:

```
Geometrie = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(polygon);
```

Index document in Nest 5.0.1 (worked fine):

```
var response = this.ElasticClient.Index<T>(geoDocument);
```

Index document in Nest 6.4.2:

```
var response = this.ElasticClient.IndexDocument<T>(geoDocument);
```

The request should be like:

```
{"field1":"correct content","geometrie":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates"::[[[5.856956,51.002753],[5.856928,51.002771],[5.856687,51.002853],[5.856956,51.002753]]]}}
```

But Nest generates a request like:

```
{"field1":"correct content","geometrie":{"type":[],"coordinates":[[[[],[]],[[],[]],[[],[]],[[],[]]]]}}
```

Response:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse field [geometrie] of type [geo_shape]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse field [geometrie] of type [geo_shape]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"Can't get text on a START_ARRAY at 1:673"}},"status":400}
```

We don't inject a SourceSerializerFactory in the connectionsettings.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a complete, minimal and verifiable example that replicates what you are seeing (see the FAQ: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I suspect that `object` in this case is a Json.NET `JObject` type, which the client does not know how to specially handle, without hooking up `JsonNetSerializer`. If you can provide a complete example, I'll be able to help further

Answer (score 0):

It is a Json.NET JObject indeed. The ConnectionSettings where created without a SourceSerializerFactory. 
Setting JsonNetSerializer.Default as SourceSerializerFactory solves the problem, thanks!

```
using System;
using Nest;
using Nest.JsonNetSerializer;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TestIndexing
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var indexName = "geodocument";
      var connectionPool = new Elasticsearch.Net.SniffingConnectionPool(new Uri[] { new Uri("http://localhost:9200") });
      var connectionSettings = new Nest.ConnectionSettings(connectionPool);
      connectionSettings.DefaultIndex(indexName);
      connectionSettings.DisableDirectStreaming();

      var elasticClient = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

      Func<TypeMappingDescriptor<GeoDocument>, ITypeMapping> typeMapping = m => m
        .Dynamic(false)
        .Properties(ps => ps
          .Keyword(k => k
            .Name(n => n.DocId))
          .GeoShape(g => g
            .PointsOnly(false)
            .Name(o => o.GeoField)));

      elasticClient.CreateIndex(new CreateIndexDescriptor(indexName).Mappings(ms => ms.Map(typeMapping)));

      var polygon = "{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[5.856956,51.002753],[5.856928,51.002771],[5.856687,51.002853],[5.856956,51.002753]]]}";
      var document = new GeoDocument()
      {
        DocId = "1",
        GeoField = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(polygon),
      };

      var indexResponse = elasticClient.IndexDocument(document);

      Console.WriteLine(indexResponse.DebugInformation);

      elasticClient.DeleteIndex(new DeleteIndexRequest(indexName));
      Console.ReadKey();
    }

    [Nest.ElasticsearchType(Name = "geoDocument", IdProperty = "DocId")]
    public class GeoDocument
    {
      [Nest.Keyword(Name = "DocId")]
      public string DocId { get; set; }

      [Nest.GeoShape(Name = "GeoField")]
      public object GeoField { get; set; }
    }
  }
}
```